# Almost empty react project after installation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have been learning React for a while now. Today when I tried to started another project it created me an almost empty project.

I used the command I always use `create-react-app 'name-of-my-app'`. It ran for a while, finished creating an app. I enter the folder with `cd 'name-of-my-app'`, run it in vscode with `code .` and there all I have is a folder `node_modules` and files `package-lock.json` and `package.json`.

I tried this three times, and every time is the same thing.
Any advice.
Thanks

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstalling create-react-app

Comment: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npx create-react-app myApp` using yarn `yarn remove create-react-app && yarn create react-app myApp`

Comment: Don't use yarn if you prefer npm for managing packages it may create versioning issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

I completely removed `create-react-app`:

```sh
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Install it again:

```sh
npm i -g create-react-app
```